# fscanf doesn't block the calling thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm dealing with fscanf function in C++ and I've confused point about fscanf. Why it doesn't block the calling thread while the stream is absolutely empty.

In my expectation, the main thread should be blocked on the fscanf function, it will be released after 3 seconds because the file stream is going to be written to after 3 seconds by the child thread.

But reality, it doesn't seem like I expected. Please somebody tells me why?

The following is my lines of code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

DWORD WINAPI subroutine(LPVOID data)
{
     FILE* file = (FILE*)data;

     std::cout << "I'll send you something after 3s" << std::endl;
     Sleep(3000);

     if (file != NULL)
     {
      std::cout << "I'm writing now" << std::endl;

      char* sentence = "Hello"; 
      fputs(sentence, file);
     }
}

int main()
{
    FILE* file = tmpfile();

    if ( file !=  NULL )
    {
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, subroutine, file, 0, NULL);

        char something[50];

        std::cout << "Blocking..." << std::endl;

        rewind(file);
        fscanf(file, "%s", something);

        std::cout << "Message is " << something << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    if (file != NULL)
    {
       fclose(file);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

============

Because people may don't understand why I think fscanf should block the calling thread.

This is why I have the above question.

```
int main()
{
    char something[50];
    fscanf(stdin, "%s", something);
    std::cout << something << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The program stopped to you enter something.

Comment: Why should it block the calling thread? It returns how many items it managed to read, or if `EOF` is reached, it returns `EOF`. Did you look at the documentation of [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a regular file, so when you are at its end `fscanf` returns `EOF`. The fact that there's another thread that in a few seconds will append some data is irrelevant, and the C library has no way to know it anyway.

Standard input blocks because when it is attached to a console it doesn't end (until the user presses Ctrl-D), so if you ask for more input and it's not ready to take it just waits (think to it as if it was a file on a disk *extremely* slow to provide the data).

Besides, using a `FILE *` backed by an actual file for cross-thread communication seems like a bad idea; besides the efficiency concerns and the headaches relative the thread-safety of sharing a `FILE *` between two threads, it maps badly to the problem at hand; what you seem to want here is a FIFO-like communication channel between two threads, not a storage device for data.

If you want to have FIFO communication between the two threads you can use - for example - an anonymous pipe or just a thread-safe message queue.